# why is it showing time limit exceeded?

Tags: c++, size, minimum, sub-array

Given an array of positive integers nums and a positive integer target, return the minimal length of a contiguous subarray [numsl, numsl+1, ..., numsr-1, numsr] of which the sum is greater than or equal to target. If there is no such subarray, return 0 instead.

```
 class Solution{
    public:
int minSubArrayLen(int target, vector<int> &nums)
{
    int right = 0;
    int left = 0;
    int size = nums.size();
    long sum = 0;
    int length = 100000;
    while (left < size)
    {
        sum = sum + nums[right];
        if (sum >= target)
        {
            length = min(length, right - left + 1);

            sum = sum - nums[left];
            left++;
            if (right != size)
                right++;
        }

        else if (right != size)
            right++;
    }
    return length;
}
};
```

Comment: It is showing time limit exceeded because your code takes too long to solve the problem. Many questions on competitive coding sites are based around knowing the "magic" algorithm to solve the problem. If you don't know it then your solution will take more than the allotted time.

Comment: If you are teaching yourself C++ then leetcode isn't the best place to do so, you will only train your problem solving skills. Leetcode often shows you very bad quality code/solutions, and its timing is very noisy. You're better of using a book or https://www.learncpp.com/. And by reading https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines. That said you need to look for another algorith that takes less steps and write some tests and debug locally.

Comment: I don't understand how this code can work. If the added number is high, you may need to increase `left` several times.

Comment: Moreover, when right arrives to size, as left is not increased, the loop is blocked.

Comment: Seems you have infinite loop, you only increase `left` when `sum >= target`, if not reach before and `nums[size - 1] <= 0` you would never have `sum >= target`...